# Issue "prerender" 'on the fly'?

Tags: prerender

Is it possible to issue a prerender statement 'on the fly'?  e.g. I use jQuery to insert this in

```
<link rel="prerender" href="www.example.com" />
```

into the  and it will execute?  Is there a way to re-issue it x times?

Basically, when someone adds something to the shopping cart I want to prerender the checkout page, but obviously I can't do that at page load because it will prerender the checkout page without the new item added.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use JS for adding the prerender hint and you can update the url to a page which should be prerendered. Basically, the browser will "forget" the previously prerendered page and prerender a new one. But, you have to be careful, if the browser doesn't have enough time to prerender the checkout page, the user will see the stale checkout page.

Considering your case, you will need to use a query parameter, otherwise, the browser won't  prerender the checkout page again after updating the href attribute, because it is already in the cache. For example, urls might look like:

```
/checkout?timestamp=111111
/checkout?timestamp=222222
/checkout?timestamp=333333
```

The user must visit the page with the latest query parameter (`/checkout?timestamp=333333`), otherwise, the browser will normally load the checkout page.